# Output Of Pig MultiStorage To a Single File

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Say i have some logs like

```
key1 something
key2 something
key3 something
```

I can use Pig MultiStorage to output the records to multiple folders based upon the key. But is there any way in MultiStorage where i can ensure that each key output contains only one file and not multiple small files as multistorage would do.

Comment: Do you want to store the same key in a single file?

Comment: yes that's what i want same key in a single file. You have a solution ?

Comment: Can you check the below solution and let me know is this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

By default `MultiStorage` will store the same key in a single file, so you no need to do anything. In the below example there are 4 keys in the different input files, after storing the keys using MultiStorage option, it will create 4 dirs `(key1,key2,key3 and key4)` and store the corresponding values in a single file. In the MultiStorage option `'0'` is nothing but `column 0`.

**input1**

```
key1,aaaa
key2,bbbb
key3,cccc
key2,bbbb
key3,eeee
key3,ffff
```

**input2**

```
key1,zzzz
key2,xxxx
key4,cccc
key3,yyyy
key4,ffff
```

**input3:**

```
key1,iiii
key2,jjjj
key3,kkkk
key4,llll
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER '/tmp/piggybank.jar';
A = LOAD 'input*' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1,f2);
STORE A INTO 'output' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('output', '0');
```

**output$ ls**

```
_SUCCESS    key1        key2        key3        key4
```

**output$ cat key1/key1-0,000**

```
key1    aaaa
key1    zzzz
key1    iiii
```

**output$ cat key2/key2-0,000**

```
key2    bbbb
key2    bbbb
key2    xxxx
key2    jjjj
```

**output$ cat key3/key3-0,000**

```
key3    cccc
key3    eeee
key3    ffff
key3    yyyy
key3    kkkk
```

**output$ cat key4/key4-0,000**

```
key4    cccc
key4    ffff
key4    llll
```

**Option2:**
The other option is using `SPLIT` command to store the same key in a single file.

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1,f2);
SPLIT A INTO k1 IF (f1=='key1'), k2 IF (f1=='key2'), k3 IF (f1=='key3');
STORE k1 INTO 'OutputKey1' USING PigStorage();
STORE k2 INTO 'OutputKey2' USING PigStorage();
STORE k3 INTO 'OutputKey3' USING PigStorage();
```

Now the output dir `OutputKey1,OutputKey2,OutputKey3` will store the result of the corresponding key values.

Comment: Hi Sivsakthi Thanks for the reply. But say they are multiple files having the sames keys. It will be processed by multiple mappers and each mapper will create a file for the key. Is there a way i can get the output to a single file in this case?

Comment: No, it will not create multiple files it will create same file only. Updated the script, please check it. I have created multiple input files(input1,input2,input3) each having same keys as well as different keys. When you store based on the keys all the  output will go into single file only.

Comment: i am getting error for the same - 2015-12-04 21:46:15,575 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected, can you help

Comment: @Avenger: try removing the "register...piggybank" line from your Pig script.  MultiStorage is now part of the Pig standard libs, and your piggybank jar was likely built for MR1.